# Write View to convert table with two columns to have multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write a SQL query for TABLE 1 to display a VIEW and get a output like the second table.

```
TABLE 1
+-------------+---------------+
|EMPLOYER ID  | EMPLOYEE NAME |
+-------------+---------------+
|1            |JOHN           |
+-------------+---------------+
|1            |MICHAEL        |
+-------------+---------------+
|1            |FRANK          |
+-------------+---------------+
|2            |JOHN           |
+-------------+---------------+
|2            |JACK           |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to write a view to display a table like this?

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|EMPLOYER ID  | EMPLOYEE NAME 1| EMPLOYEE NAME 2|EMPLOYEE NAME 3|
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|1            | JOHN           | MICHAEL        | FRANK         |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|2            | JOHN           | JACK           | NULL          |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: Why do you want a VIEW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select employer_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then employee_name end) as employee_name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then employee_name end) as employee_name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then employee_name end) as employee_name_3
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employer_id order by employee_name) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by employer_id;
```

This works for three names (and can obviously be extended to more).  However, if you don't don't the number of names, it might be more convenient to combine them into a single string:

```
select employer_id,
       group_concat(employee_name) as employee_names
from table1
group by employer_id;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what its doing it but it worked, so thank you very much.